# Spring context resource cannot be resolved as url

Tags: java, spring

I have a `Spring's application-context.xml` and `custom-context.xml` that overrides it.
When in custom-config.xml I create a bean like this

```
<bean id="dir" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg value="${root.smth:}/WEB-INF/mySecretFolder/"/>
</bean>
```

and using it as dependency like this

```
 <bean id="secretBean" class="com.project.secret">
    <constructor-arg ref="dir"/>
</bean>
```

it says that it cannot resolve `${root.smth:}/WEB-INF/mySecretFolder/` as url.

I resolved this issue by creating a list like:

```
<util:list id=dirList value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>${root.smth:}/WEB-INF/mySecretFolder/</value>
</util:list>
```

and using it in constructor like this:

```
public someConstr(@Value("#{dirList[0]}" Resource dir)
...
```

Why is that? Why path cannot be resolved when I create bean for it and can be resolved when I put it in a list? Is it because list is of type `String`?

Comment: First of all, the list is of type 'java.lang.Spring',  is this a typo?

Comment: no, not a typo. It works that way.

Comment: Maybe it is because it is resolved differently when I inject String in a resource type argument parameter?

Comment: There is no Spring class in java.lang. You probably meant java.lang.String.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was probably a bit careless while writing post and reading your comment. You are right. I fixed that.

Comment: are you sure that  using the second form you get a valid path and not something like "${root.smth:}/WEB-INF/mySecretFolder/"? where ${root.smth:} is defined?

Comment: If your exception literally contains `${root.smth:}` it means the property placeholder resolution did not work for some reason.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. But for what reason and why the second approach works?

Comment: Are both approaches in the same XML (the one not working and the one working)?

Comment: Yes, they both are. I think it has something to do with difference between ways it resolves resources

Comment: Do you mean that the system property root.smth is not resolved by Spring Framework,  that make ${root.smth:}/WEB-INF/mySecretFolder/ not a valid url?

Comment: Well it is resolved when I put it in a String list and inject is as a resource

Comment: I think if you need the property resolved inside a string literal, you need to define a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a property place holder in custom-context.xml, try add this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
```

The function of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is to resolves ${...} placeholders against local properties and/or system properties and environment variables.
You can refer to the Java [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

Comment: Could you be more specific? What does it do and how it helps.

Comment: I tried on my laptop, it works after I added the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. I guess Spring need some config to resolve the property inside the a string. I always add this configurer into my context xml, so I never realize that spring can do the resolution by default ;). BTW, I use spring 4.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: It creates relaticve URL, how can I get absolute?

Answer (score 0):

It probably has an issue resolving the path in the resource constructor. 
Maybe this will work:
Create a bean of type String to contain the resolved path and than reference it as follows:

```
<bean id="path" class="java.Lang.String"> <constructor-arg value="${root.smth:}/WEB-INF/mySecretFolder/"/> </bean>

<bean id="dir" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource"> <constructor-arg ref=path/> </bean>
```